# Applying A Category to Existing Posts Where Page Title Matches Regex

Tags: php, categories, title, regex

I have a whole bunch of posts that I need to add a category to (too many to do via Bulk Actions). They all follow a predictable/consistent post title naming structure that could be matched via regex.

My pseudo-code is:

```
IF post title matches regex "X"
THEN apply Category "Y" (ie to the matching posts)
```

I was thinking that this is probably something I can run one-time in a custom PHP script?

I found `wp_set_post_categories` ([link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_categories/)), but not sure how to use it to assign a category to all posts based on the title text pattern... It seems to be made for updating individual posts?

Thanks

Comment: Since this sounds like a one-time update, have you considered using a plugin to export your post data into a CSV, make the necessary changes in Google Docs or Microsoft Excel, and then importing the updated categories back in?

Comment: No I never thought of that! I didn't realize you could export post data to a CSV. There are a huge number of posts (>100,000), which I why I need a method of doing this... Do you have a guide or anything you could point to, and/or add it as an answer?

Comment: `wp_set_object_terms` may also be helpful here?